routing LAN connections among clients on same ISP router device
Trying to understand why I cannot reach other LAN devices on a ISP modem. WiFi is off. I'm using two of the 4 LAN ports on the back.
I have one ISP modem at 192.168.1.1 (LAN), WAN is not relevant, as it is the public IP, let's say 1.2.3.4. Already triple checked there is no option for client isolation or the likes for the LAN side (at least visible on the UI). It's set up to offer DHCP from .2 to .200
Then on one LAN port I have a device 192.168.1.101/24 (it should receive connections from all interfaces on port 22. I tested moving it to a proper router using same DHCP IPs).
I plugged another device on another LAN port of the ISP modem and got 192.168.1.2/24
It's a Linux device with NetworkManager handling DHCP.
It gets the following address and route:
$ ip a
2: enp3s0f4u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:c3:97:fe:2e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0f4u1
       valid_lft 258516sec preferred_lft 258516sec
    inet6 fe80::b4c3:97ff:fefe:2efb/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

 $ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0f4u1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.2 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0f4u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100 

1.2.3.4 -wan- [modem] -lan- 192.168.1.1
                             |-port1->192.168.1.2
                             `-port2->192.168.1.101

But it cannot reach that other device. The trace is weird as it does not look like it even reaches the ISP modem/router. But maybe I'm just clueless to the output here:
 $ tracepath -n 192.168.1.101
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.2                                         3030.125ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1500

compared to the trace to the router itself
 $ tracepath -n4  192.168.1.1
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.089ms reached
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           0.857ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1 


The router has an option to setup port forwards. I set them up (wan)*:22->(lan)192.168.1.101:22 (plus the ICMP ping stuff). I can connect and ping from outside to 192.168.1.101 (thru the external IP) fine.
outside4Gnetwork$ ssh 1.2.3.4
root@192.168.1.101 $ ...

But the port mapper is only on the WAN interface, from the LAN it doesn't work
192.168.1.2$ ssh 1.2.3.4
(times out) (expected, as mentioned in one comment, this would be hairpin/NAT loopback)

192.168.1.2$ ssh 192.196.1.1
(connection refused) (again, expected there's no mapping from the lan side, nor ssh server on the ISP modem)

192.168.1.2$ ssh 1.2.3.4 -J external.server.example.com
root@192.168.1.101$ ... (works. since it goes via an external jumphost and back into the WAN)

It is a Sagemcom Fast 5657 device and there's no firewall or routing settings on the UI.
So, what I'm trying to understand is why the devices are isolated on the wired LAN side? Why can't 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.101 talk between them?

You're trying to connect from inside through the NAT rule? That looks like the usual "NAT hairpin" or "NAT loopback" issue – there have been several threads regarding why that normally cannot work.

wouldn't hairpin be the case, which is not present on the examples: 192.168.1.2$ ssh 1.2.3.4 (lan ip -> external ip)? the only example i show using the moden wan interface is exactly when i go to the outside via a jumphost and back into the wan (to prove the port map works, to clear it is not a firewall issue anywhere). Everything in my question is about the same LAN 192.168.1.0/24... no NAT should be involved, i hope. (will add wan interfaces to the question to make it clearer)

@grawity oh! i see, i mention the hairpin and the port forward too much in the end! I added comments that the failures are expected, i just wanted to show that NAT and port forward from the outside works fine. That isn't what i was trying to use, just to make a point the clients are OK because portmapper works. I tried to make it clearer with a couple comments about things being expected in the question. thanks!

What do arp -an or ip n say? A simple ping to the other IP? tcpdump? Also this doc indicates that different ports can be mapped to different VLANs, no idea whether that's something hardcoded, controlled by the ISP, or which you can change yourself. Which LAN ports are you using?

Also have you tried adding one or two WiFi devices? Can you ping between either of the wired devices and a WiFi device? Between WiFi devices? It's quite possible there's client isolation (forced) enabled. Stupid, but then the only option would be to add a switch (or router, but that would be overkill).

Note that the trace path output is "normal": when you try to reach 192.168.1.101, it doesn't go to the router (only the switch inside the device which also acts as a router): since that IP is in the same range, IP knows it needs to send the packet directly to the destination MAC. So it does an ARP lookup (comes up empty), an ARP request, and since it apparently doesn't receive a response, it marks the destination as invalid (host unreachable, !H).

@jcaron arp -n/ip n on both sides show each other with the correct mac, but "STALE". I did not expect that. ...From what you mention about tracepath, should i force packets to go via the router somehow? my ISP modem is a dumbed down (if possible) version of that one. I'm trying to get them to send me one with PPoE bypass available

if i ping them arp changes from STALE to INCOMPLETE. So I guess the ISP router is client isolating the LAN ports?

I'm surprised that you actually see the address of the other device in the ARP table. I'd be curious find out what you can see using tcpdump, i.e. whether each device sees broadcasts from the other.

@jcaron any "reachable" ip (as per routing tables) that i try to connect shows up as INCOMPLETE. But then they move to FAILED. I'm trying to understand why they move to STALE in this case but not finding anything relevant.

I don't remember the details of the various states, but IIRC INCOMPLETE means ARP request sent, and FAILED means no response within timeout. But I don't understand how you could have the correct remote MAC if they are not able to communicate.

You need to localize/isolate the problem.
The simplest way to do that is to buy/borrow a simple switch and connect all your devices to that (the LAN side of the router and both your hosts). One of two things will happen:
It Starts Working
In which case, you know it is a problem with the router and you can either, invest more time trying to figure out what the heck is up with the router or just live with having an extra switch.
It Still Doesn't Work
In which case you know it's not the router - since it's not involved, in such cases you need to enumerate other possibilities:

Bad piece of wire.
Bad hardware on the hosts.
Something wrong with the network config on the hosts.
Security/Fire-walling on the hosts.
...


It "starts working" with mikrotik router, but i need to use the ISP router. I'm trying to understand what a consumer ISP modem might be screwing up to do that. The UI show all "firewall" off. No option for "client isolation" etc. But i'm not sure how to debug to be sure of what is going on.

An additional router introduces complexity, I am suggesting introducing a (dumb) switch to isolate the problem.

Agreed. that might be the final solution. I was actually trying to have less devices by using those ports, since i can't not use that modem. but now it is becoming clear i should just add a proper switch there.

TBH - I strongly suspect that it still won't work after you add the switch, however given either outcome: you have new data to help isolate the issue.


then on one port I have a device 192.168.1.101

That looks like manual configuration. Make sure you don't forget:

the same subnet mask as the rest: 255.255.255.0 or /24
default gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS server: 192.168.1.1 (or whatever the others are using)


Good guess. But I just changed the DHCP range from 100-200 to 2-200 and that host stuck with the IP for months.

Router firewall.
There's two ways in which this one can be in your way. First, it might not allow anyone to talk to anyone on your network. This is a common setting for guest wifi points, and I've seen it in other places.
Second, you mention changing your dhcp range. Some routers have a "group" of ip-addresses called "lan", and will only allow communication within that group. Basically it's then re-using that group for both the dhcp server and the firewall.
I see that you have turned off the firewall temporarily for testing, but with consumer grade equipment you can't always know what that means. Does it keep failing if you renew the IP for your .101, which should then get .3?

Good points! this excuse of a device doesn't have any setting for firewall, not even the joke "low, medium, high" dropdown I usually see on those. I meant I turned off firewall on the clients. About client-isolation, I wouldn't expect they do that on physical ports, but i guess now blocking your smart TV worm is a thing ISP have to worry about...  The dhcp was a good guess, so i moved both to the same range using fixed leases, but same end result.
